# Addint last token into 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, token

Hello i've got an array with different names, and i need to take their surnames and put into different array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char ame[100][100] = {"Charles Thompson","Andy Hardy","Christopher de Charls-morson"};
char surname[100][100];

int main(void) {
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       char *last = strrchr(name[i], ' ');
       if (last != NULL) {
           printf("Last token: '%s'\n", last+1);
           
          surname[i]=(last+1); // <----problem part
       }
  }  
}
```

if i coment out the surname[i] line, the code works and prints out their surnames, i just cant add it to array

desired output:

```
for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
   printf(surname[k]); // <--just to test print
}
```

would result in

```
Thompson <- surname[0] position
Hardy <- surname[1] position
Charls-morson <- surname[2] position
```

based on assigment i should seperate it based on whitespace, the last name with - is ok, also it needs to be as string, becaouse later on i need to make a function where i compare imput surname with array and find it position

Comment: `surname[i]` is an array. You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. To copy strings, use `strcpy`.

Comment: i put strcpy(surname[i],(last+1)) it worked thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I replaced:

```
surname[i]=(last+1);
```

With:

```
strcpy(surname[i],(last+1))
```

and it worked.